# Why is catkin_make_isolated trying to build so much?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically I don't understand the ROS build system.

I installed ROS from source on a Raspberry Pi 4 under Raspbian Buster Stretch using this  [method](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Melodic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi).  I also managed to get raspicam_node to compile and install. I used Raspbian because it provides support for the Pi's GPU.

Everything works, but whenever I try to build my own package with catkin_make_isolated, ROS appears to try to rebuild the entire system - it takes hours !  Also I don't know if I should be using catkin_make(like I always used to), or catkin_make_isolated. I don't know why ROS wants to rebuild the whole system - I installed the system to /opt/ROS/melodic, and thought that it should now just recompile my own package. Something has got very messed up.

My directory structure is now:

- catkin_ws

  - build
  - build_isolated
  - devel
  - devel_isolated
  - install
  - src

I don't think I should have build *and* build_isolated etc.  Some packages exist in both, and some are just in one. I don't know why I have both.

Any clarification would be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363443/why-is-catkin_make_isolated-trying-to-build-so-much-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2020-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi elpidiovaldez,

You have this directory structure because you have used `catkin_build` (build and install) and `catkin_build_isolated` (build_isolated and install_isolated) in this workspace. You should use only one.

- `catkin_make` treats the entire workspace as a single cmake project, and builds it with a single invocation of cmake. Since catkin_make treats the entire workspace as a single package, it's faster for incremental builds that only change code, but slower when you need to regenerate the build files, and more sensitive to dependency issues between packages.
- `catkin_make_isolated` treats each package as a separate cmake project, and builds and installs each separately, in dependency order. This is why it's able to build plain cmake packages.

You can find more detail in this [thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/320613/catkin_make-vs-catkin_make_isolated-which-is-preferred/)

If you want to build only your package try to run:

```
catkin_make_isolated --pkg <your package name>
```

for more usefull arguments and/or options:

```
catkin_make_isolated -h
```

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-16**:
Suggestion to the OP: read up on workspace overlaying, and don't re-use the workspace you used to build your base ROS install for development of your own packages. Use a new, overlayed workspace for that.